# Optimization with SAT4J

Tags: algorithm, optimization, sat4j

I am trying to solve the problem below using [SAT4J](http://www.SAT4J.org) . My question is how to specify the problem to SAT4J using their API.

Here is the problem:

```
boolean[50][50][20] variables; int[50][50][20] utility;

maximize Σ(over i,j,k) variables[i][j][k] * utility[i][j][k]
```

such that:

```
for each (i, j): Σ(over x) variables[i][j][x] <= 1

for each (i, j): Σ(over x) variables[i][x][j] <= 1

for each (i, j): Σ(over x) variables[x][i][j] <= 1
```